# To remove the newline character of a variable in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have my perl code like this

```
my $test = "gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg 
Starting 
gahgahd vvsfdh";

$test=~ m/(.*)Starting(.*)/;
print"test value = $1 \n";
```

when I execute this code, I get nothing i.e.,

```
test value =
```

But when the `$test` strings are in the same line i.e.,

```
my $test ="gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg Starting gahgahd vvsfdh";
```

I get the result for the print statement to be

```
test value = gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg.
```

What's the problem with the first case. The only difference is the inclusion of newline space. How to make the first code get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot doesn't match a newline unless you use the `/s` modifier.

```
$test =~ /(.*)Starting(.*)/s;
```

Are you sure you want the newlines to be part of the captured strings?

Comment: @nandeeshv: Note that the second `(.*)` is superfluous unless you also want to use `$2`

Comment: Actually I am trying to store the results printed on the terminal. I am running my make file and storing the result printed as below. system("make"); my $var = `.\/fir.exe`; I am using backsticks to store the results printed on the screen

Comment: @nandeeshv: Then it would have been better to say so in the question. If you use `` my @result = `command` ``. Then the output is already split into lines, one per array element. But what do you want to do with the result?

Answer (score 2):

The `s` modifier to regexes causes `.` to match newlines.

So your regex should be

```
$test=~ m/(.*)Starting(.*)/s;
```

to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: Wow!! What a rapid reply. Thanks a lot, @bytepusher. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have corrected your regex. But if your goal is to split a string into lines, use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $test = "gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg 
Starting 
gahgahd vvsfdh";
my @lines = split /\n/, $test;
say "First line:  $lines[0]";
say "Second line: $lines[1]";
say "Third line:  $lines[2]";
```

If your goal is to get the first and third lines, using `split` means you don't need to know what the content of the second line is.

Comment: One could also split on "Starting", which is what the OP seems to be trying to do ;)

Comment: Or , using the dot's fickleness as it was intended, `my @lines = $test =~ /.+/g` (or `/(.*)\n/g` if you're interested in blank lines)

Comment: @Borodin Clever, but needlessly obtuse.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I try never to be in the position of having text with embedded newlines anyway, and there's usually more selection to be done than just finding newlines. Your solution seems like shell-thinking to me.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `.` matches any character except newline, so your `.*` won't match beyond the end of the line

You can simply account for that whitespace using `\s*`. `\s` matches any whitespace character, and newline is a whitespace character

```
my $test = "gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg 
Starting 
gahgahd vvsfdh";

$test =~ m/(.*)\s*Starting/;
print "test value = $1 \n";
```

#### output

```
test value = gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to achieve the solution using substitution and multi-line matching.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = "gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg 
Starting 
gahgahd vvsfdh";

$test=~ s/\n//mg;
print"test value = $test \n";
```

The output is as below,

```
test value = gsfdsd gsfgsfg sfghsdg Starting gahgahd vvsfdh
```

Comment: You can drop `/m` modifier as you are not using `^` or `$`

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you @Dada i didn't notice at first.